# How to store product catalog in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm about to store data of product catalog in Eleasticsearch with simplified model depicted here:
[Product catalog model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QorZp.png)

I can store entire product as one document:

```
{
  "productNumber": "123456",
  "brand": "Acme Inc.",
  "title": "T-Shirt",
  "featured": false,
  "promo": true,
  "categories": [
    { "categoryId": "124", "categoryPath": "/10/123/124", "title": "T-Shirts", "titlePath": "Men's/Summer/T-Shirts" },
    { "categoryId": "666", "categoryPath": "/20/666", "title": "Men's", "titlePath": "Promos / Men's" }
  ],
  "variants": [
    {
      "sku": "123456-01",
      "color": "red",
      "size": "XL",
      "prices": [
        { "pricelist": "EUR-RRP", "currency": "EUR", "price": 200, "discountPc": 0, "discounted": false },
        { "pricelist": "EUR-PROMO", "currency": "EUR", "price": 180, "discountPc": 10, "discounted": true }
      ],
      "inventories": [
        { "inventoryId": "INV-001", "stockCount": 0 },
        { "inventoryId": "INV-002", "stockCount": 5 }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is whether this is best aproach if I have these requirement on searching the catalog, or should I split it to multiple indexes with relation:

- pageable list of Products
- sortable by brand, title, price, discount
- each search request has pre-configured search params as follows:

  - RootCategory - include just products where "categoryPath" starts with (eg. "/10/123")
  - Locale - product title/description is localized to multiple languages
  - OnStockOnly boolean flag - defines whether include only products which have at least one variant on one inventory
  - Pricelist - id of the pricelist to be used
- Search params defined by user:

  - Price range "from-to" (price is from defined pricelist as stated above)
  - Facets: product brand, productVariant color, productVariant size
  - Flags (checkboxes - apply only if check): featured product, promo product, discounted price (for at least one product variant)

Note that catalog will be multi-lingual, so the idea is to create index per language (eg. catalog-en, catalog-de, etc.)